# How to calculate a continuous function once and access values later?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, function-construction

I have a function that involves a numerical calculation:

```
h[v_]:=NIntegrate[f[x]*Log[p[x, v]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

I need to visualize how well a bunch of other functions of v match h[v], so I'm doing a lot of this:

```
Plot[g1[v]-h[v],{v,0,2}]
Plot[g2[v]-h[v],{v,0,2}]
Plot[g3[v]-h[v],{v,0,2}]
```

Is there a good way to somehow record h[v] so that I'm not calculating it over and over and over for all those v's?

And I need to make plots on-the-fly as new functions get generated, so I can't put them all in a list together and do this:

```
{g1[v],g2[v],g3[v]}-h[v]
```

Comment: `Interpolation` ?

Comment: [`FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)

Comment: @MichaelE2  Yes, I could code up an interpolation scheme, but I was hoping something a little more elegant and accurate was possible, perhaps even built in.